# How to validate email from dummy emails?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, email-validation, dart-pub

I am currently working on a project and need validation for validating dummy emails like
mailinator or yopmail.
These emails should not go through but I can't get any regex for this particular issue.

I have tried different regex but none them worked.

Comment: What is your source of dummy emails?

Answer (score 4):

I made a [list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HYv7Ij2QKU6t-X6hzthjmGwxscK9XDidnUzSNMcENbo/edit?usp=sharing) of all the disposable domains. You can use this list to validate disposable email.

Exp:

```
final disposableEmail = [
 "xxyxi.com",
 "musiccode.me",
]

final splitList = _emailController.text.split("@");
if (disposableEmail.contains(splitList[1].trim())) {
    print('Registration with temporary-email-address not allowed');
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the email validator plugin from the pub.dev to validate email easily
https://pub.dev/packages/email_validator

example code

```
void main() {

    var email = "fredrik@gmail.com";

    assert(EmailValidator.validate(email));
}
```